# Where does django dev server (manage.py runserver) get its path from?

Tags: python, django, path, django-manage.py, devserver

I recently moved a django app from `c:\Users\user\django-projects\foo\foobar` to `c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\foo\foobar` (which is on the python path). I started a new app in the `django-projects` directory, and added `foo.foobar` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. When I try to run the dev server (`manage.py runserver`) for my new app, I get the error `ImportError: No module named foobar`.

Looking through the traceback, it's looking in the `c:\Users\user\django-projects\foo\..\foo\foobar` for the `foobar` app. I checked my `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables, and neither point to `c:\Users\user\django-projects\foo` and It doesn't show up in `sys.path` when I run the python interpreter.

I'm guessing I somehow added `c:\Users\user\django-projects\foo` to django's path sometime along the development of `foo` but I don't remember how I did it.

So, with all that lead up, my question is "how do I make manage.py look in `c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages` instead of `c:\Users\user\django-projects\foo`?"

Thanks,

- Lexo

Comment: You can change the path by editing `sys.path`. However, I am guessing that your `site-packages\foo` directory is simply missing an `__init__.py`

Comment: Is `sys.path` the only place that `manage.py` looks? If so, how come it's still looking in the non-existent `django-projects\foo` directory? Also, I do have the `__init__.py` file in `site-packages\foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manage.py` imports settings.py from the current directory and pass `settings` as parameter to `execute_manager`. You probably defined project root in settings.py.

Comment: Thanks. I checked my `settings.py` and there's no trace of `django-projects` in it at all. I'm beginning to think I'm going crazy. I'll do some more testing and see what I can come up with.

Comment: did you try to use the managed shell (`python manage.py shell`) to see what's in sys.path. `..../foo` should be the first one there. Just to check... as if it is not there, I don't know how to correct! but if it's there, I think your problem is not a path problem. Maybe permissions? Is `__init__.py` empty?

Comment: I fixed the problem (see below), but you did answer my original question, so I marked your question as the correct one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to see it's solved! :) and thanks for the accept even with a very indirect help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, although I don't know which solution worked. First, I deleted the `.pyc` files from my project, then I reindexed my Windows search (I'm guessing this did it). This changed the error message to the correct directory. After which, i realized I had

```
from baz import settings
```

in my `foobar/baz/models.py` file, which was causing the problem all along. I changed this to

```
import settings
```

which fixed the problem. Thanks to laurent for all your help :-)